# Is it possible to download a repository folder with all/needed Maven artifacts?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, maven-2

I have a repository folder inside .m2 but it doesn't have some of the artifacts I need. Is there a place I can download a repository folder from with the most used artifacts or is there a place where I can add artifacts from into my existing repository folder?

Comment: Why not using the default mechnanism of Maven and just add the needed deps into the pom file and they will downloaded automatically .. If you miss something in your local cache ($HOME/.m2/repository) you should add them to your pom file... ?

Comment: Maybe he's going travelling in the mountains and will be offline from maven central repo....

Comment: Just some confusion I have as I'm new to using Maven, is the repository folder built based on what's in your pom.xml or is your pom.xml loaded based on what's in your repository folder?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run this command:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=OUTPUT_DIR
```

replace OUTPUT_DIR with the directory you want to copy the dependencies